# Get Values using Key from SimpleListAdaptor

Tags: java

How can I get a specific value from a list if the list has 4 keys? I want to get only `Table_id` value from the below code:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        String xx = adaptor.getItem(0)+"";
        Log.d(TAG,"Position : "+ xx);
    }
});
```

The returned log:

```
Position : {Schedule_Class=No Class, Schedule_Place=Mama, Table_id=31, Schedule_Time=12:00 AM}
```

Comment: try adaptor.getItem(0).Table_id or adaptor.getItem(0)("Table_id")

Comment: adaptor.getItem(0).Table_id or adaptor.getItem(0)("Table_id") Did not work

Comment: I'm sorry. I hope someone is able to give you a better answer.

Comment: @TamerTaha Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: adaptor.getItem(0).Position.Table_id, perhaps